# Accessibility focus is reset in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, talkback, accessibility

I have a button on the screen, when I open a new Fragment by clicking on that button with TalkBack and return to the previous Fragment (`fm.popBackStack()`), the button should get accessability focus again. But instead, the focus is reset to the first element on the screen as on the first visit. The same with RecyclerView, when I open a new Fragment by clicking on an item, then when I return, the focus should return to the same item on which it was. It works as expected with activity, but not with fragments. How it can be fixed?

Tested on Android 9, 11 and Fragment 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1 versions

[image]

Comment: What version of Fragments are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I tried on 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, I made an example rep https://github.com/RI42/Accessibility-Focus

Answer (score -1):

This will be a long answer because this question has various solutions depending on your needs, and I decided to take time and be thorough because accessibility is essential!

###### tl;dr solution for your problem:

To correctly save the instance state of Fragment you should do the following:

1. In the fragment, save instance state by overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore in `onActivityCreated()`:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's state here
    }
}
...
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    
    //Save the fragment's state here
}
}
```

2. And important point, in the activity, you have to save the fragment's instance in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore in `onCreate()`

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private MyFragment 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //Restore the fragment's instance
            mMyFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "myFragmentName");
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            
        //Save the fragment's instance
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "myFragmentName", mMyFragment);
    }
}
```

### Deep dive - Managing UI state

You can efficiently save and restore the UI state by dividing the work among the various types of persistence mechanisms. In most cases, each of these mechanisms should store a different kind of data used in the activity, based on the tradeoffs of data complexity, access speed, and lifetime:

- Local persistence: Stores all data you don't want to lose if you open and close the activity.
  Example: A collection of song objects, including audio files and metadata.
  `ViewModel`: Stores all the data needed to display the associated UI Controller in memory.
  Example: The song objects of the most recent search and search query.
- `onSaveInstanceState()`: Stores a small amount of data needed to quickly reload the activity state if the system stops and then recreates the UI Controller. Instead of storing complex objects here, persist the complex objects in local storage and store a unique ID for these objects in onSaveInstanceState()
  Example: Storing the most recent search query.
  As an example, consider an activity that allows you to search through your library of songs. Here's how different events should be handled:

The ViewModel immediately delegates this data locally when the user adds a song. If this newly added song should be shown in the UI, you should also update the data in the ViewModel object to reflect the addition of the song. Remember to do all database inserts off of the main thread.

When the user searches for a song, whatever complex song data you load from the database for the UI Controller should be immediately stored in the ViewModel object. You should also save the search query itself in the ViewModel object.

When the activity goes into the background, the system calls onSaveInstanceState(). You should save the search query in the onSaveInstanceState() bundle. This small amount of data is easy to save. It's also all the information you need to get the activity back into its current state.

---

### Options for preserving UI state

When the user's expectations about UI state do not match default system
behaviour, you must save and restore the user's UI state to ensure that the
system-initiated destruction is transparent to the user.

Each of the options for preserving UI state vary along the following dimensions that impact the user experience:

|  | ViewModel | Saved instance state | Persistent storage |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Storage location | in memory | serialized to disk | on disk or network |  |
| Survives configuration change | Yes | Yes | Yes |  |
| Survives system-initiated process death | No | Yes | Yes |  |
| Survives user complete activity dismissal/onFinish() | No | No | Yes |  |
| Data limitations | complex objects are fine, but space is limited by available memory | only for primitive types and simple, small objects such as String | only limited by disk space or cost/time of retrieval from the network resource |  |
| Read/write time | quick (memory access only) | slow (requires serialization/deserialization and disk access) | slow (requires disk access or network transaction) |  |

---

---

### SavedStateRegistry

Beginning with Fragment 1.1.0, UI controllers, such as an Activity or Fragment, implement `SavedStateRegistryOwner` and provide a `SavedStateRegistry` that is bound to that controller. `SavedStateRegistry` allows components to hook into your UI controller's saved state to consume or contribute to it. For example, the Saved State module for `ViewModel` uses SavedStateRegistry to create a `SavedStateHandle` and provide it to your `ViewModel` objects. You can retrieve the `SavedStateRegistry` from within your UI controller by calling `getSavedStateRegistry()`.

Components that contribute to the saved state must implement `SavedStateRegistry`.`SavedStateProvider` defines a single method called `saveState()`. The `saveState()` method allows your component to return a Bundle containing any state that should be saved from that component. `SavedStateRegistry` calls this method during the saving state phase of the UI controller's lifecycle.

```
class SearchManager implements SavedStateRegistry.SavedStateProvider {
    private static String QUERY = "query";
    private String query = null;
    ...

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Bundle saveState() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(QUERY, query);
        return bundle;
    }
}
```

To register a `SavedStateProvider`, call `registerSavedStateProvider()` on the `SavedStateRegistry`, passing a key to associate with the provider's data as well as the provider. The previously saved data for the provider can be retrieved from the saved state by calling `consumeRestoredStateForKey()` on the `SavedStateRegistry`, passing in the key associated with the provider's data.

Within an Activity or Fragment, you can register a `SavedStateProvider` in `onCreate()` after calling `super.onCreate()`. Alternatively, you can set a `LifecycleObserver` on a `SavedStateRegistryOwner`, which implements `LifecycleOwner`, and register the `SavedStateProvider` once the `ON_CREATE` event occurs. Using a `LifecycleObserver` lets you decouple the registration and retrieval of the previously saved state from the `SavedStateRegistryOwner` itself.

```
class SearchManager implements SavedStateRegistry.SavedStateProvider {
    private static String PROVIDER = "search_manager";
    private static String QUERY = "query";
    private String query = null;

    public SearchManager(SavedStateRegistryOwner registryOwner) {
        registryOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver((LifecycleEventObserver) (source, event) -> {
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE) {
                SavedStateRegistry registry = registryOwner.getSavedStateRegistry();

                // Register this object for future calls to saveState()
                registry.registerSavedStateProvider(PROVIDER, this);

                // Get the previously saved state and restore it
                Bundle state = registry.consumeRestoredStateForKey(PROVIDER);

                // Apply the previously saved state
                if (state != null) {
                    query = state.getString(QUERY);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Bundle saveState() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(QUERY, query);
        return bundle;
    }

    ...
}

class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
    private SearchManager searchManager = new SearchManager(this);
    ...
}
```

### Use ViewModel to handle configuration changes

`ViewModel` is ideal for storing and managing UI-related data while actively using the application. It allows quick access to UI data and helps you avoid refetching data from network or disk across rotation, window resizing, and other commonly occurring configuration changes.

`ViewModel` retains the data in memory, which means it is cheaper to retrieve than data from the disk or the network. A ViewModel is associated with an activity (or some other lifecycle owner) - it stays in memory during a configuration change. The system automatically associates the ViewModel with the new activity instance that results from the configuration change.

ViewModels are automatically destroyed by the system when your user backs out of your activity or fragment or if you call `finish()`, which means the state will be cleared as the user expects in these scenarios.

Unlike saved instance states, ViewModels are destroyed during a system-initiated process death. This is why you should use ViewModel objects in combination with `onSaveInstanceState()` (or some other disk persistence), stashing identifiers in `savedInstanceState` to help view models reload the data after system death.

If you already have an in-memory solution in place for storing your UI state across configuration changes, you may not need to use `ViewModel`.

---

### Use onSaveInstanceState() as backup to handle system-initiated process death

The `onSaveInstanceState()` callback stores data needed to reload the state of a UI controller, such as an activity or a fragment, if the system destroys and later recreates that controller.

Saved instance state bundles persist through configuration changes and process death but are limited by storage and speed because `onSavedInstanceState()` serializes data to disk. Serialization can consume a lot of memory if the serialized objects are complicated. Because this process happens on the main thread during a configuration change, long-running serialization can cause dropped frames and visual stutter.

Do not use `onSavedInstanceState()` to store large amounts of data, such as bitmaps or complex data structures requiring lengthy serialization or deserialization. Instead, store only primitive types and simple, small objects such as String. As such, use `onSaveInstanceState()` to store a minimal amount of data necessary, such as an ID, to re-create the data necessary to restore the UI back to its previous state should the other persistence mechanisms fail. Most apps should implement `onSaveInstanceState()` to handle system-initiated process death.

Depending on your app's use cases, you might not need to use `onSaveInstanceState()` at all.

Comment: Thanks you, but it doesn't answer my question. First of all, `onSaveInstanceState` won't call between `replace` fragment transaction, Second you didn't answer what i should save and how it can be saved (how to find accessibility focused view, also not all Views that can be focused have ID), what to do with RecyclerViews and how to restore accessibility focus